# Show all rows that meet a certain criteria in a pop up window

Tags: excel, vba, loops, msgbox

I am trying to create a pop up that returns either an entire row of data or just the first 3 columns whenever column E is greater than 1. The tricky part is that this has to happen when the "close" button in an another popup that collects data is clicked.

So far I can only get it to return each record in a separate popup by using a loop but I would like to show all cases in the same pop up. Here's what I have:

column A is is Last Name
column B is First Name
column C is a location number 
column D is a date
column E is a simple count cell that shows how many times a First and Last Name occur

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Dim wsx As Worksheet
Set wsx = Worksheets("SuspectData")
Dim xRow As Long
Dim countingX As Integer
countingX = 2

'find last row in database'
xRow = wsx.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

'prompt warning'
With wsx

Do While countingX <= xRow
    If Range("E" & countingX) > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Suspect " & Range("B" & countingX) & " " & Range("A" & countingX) & " at Unit " & Range("C" & countingX))

    End If
    countingX = countingX + 1
Loop

End With

 Unload Me

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all cases to return inside of one popup, you should add the cases to a string, and have the popup call the string outside of the loop

```
Dim s as String
s = ""
Do While countingX <= xRow
    If Range("E" & countingX) > 1 Then
        s = s & vbnewline & "Suspect " & Range("B" & countingX) & " " & Range("A" & countingX) & " at Unit " & Range("C" & countingX)

    End If
    countingX = countingX + 1
Loop

MsgBox s
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very simple and elegant solution.